# Close event of lightning tab

Tags: lightning

I have created a page and showed a component on that page. I am opening that page in the lightning tab from lightning quick action. I want to call a apex method whenever user close that page either from browser close or from tab close. So to achieve above requirement is there any way?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

On top of my head you won't be able to call apex when the browser is closed in Native Salesforce.  There is JS [onunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) method that you can try, but it might not always work according to W3Schools.

> Note: Due to different browser settings, this onunload event may not
>   always work as expected.

In Native SF when Tab or Subtab is closed you will be able to do that by subscribing to `lightning:tabClosed`

> [lightning:tabClosed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:tabClosed/documentation) is an application event that indicates a tab has been closed successfully. This event is supported in Lightning console apps only.

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />  
    <aura:handler event="lightning:tabClosed" action="{! c.onTabClosed }"/> 
</aura:component>
```